# How to show 0.00 when check box not checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

How to display 0.00 in the totalcost field when check box not checked ?

```
<form id="form1">
<input type="checkbox" id='game0' value="9.99"  onclick="UpdateCost()">Game 1 ( 9.99)<br>
<input type="checkbox" id='game1' value="19.99" onclick="UpdateCost()">Game 2 (19.99)<br>
<input type="checkbox" id='game2' value="27.50" onclick="UpdateCost()">Game 3 (27.50)<br>
<input type="checkbox" id='game3' value="45.65" onclick="UpdateCost()">Game 4 (45.65)<br>
<input type="checkbox" id='game4' value="87.20" onclick="UpdateCost()">Game 5 (87.20)<br>
<input type="checkbox" id='game5' value="87.20" onclick="UpdateCost()">Game 5 (87.20)<br>    
<input type="text" id="totalcost" value="">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var clickHandlers = (function () {
    var form1 = document.getElementById("form1"),
        totalcost = document.getElementById("totalcost"),
        // if this is always the last input in the form, we could avoid hitting document again with
        // totalcost  = form1[form1.length - 1];
        sum = 0;
        form1.onclick = function (e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            var thisInput = e.target || e.srcElement;
            if (thisInput.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {
                if (thisInput.checked) {
                    sum  += parseFloat(thisInput.value);
                }  else {
                    if (thisInput.type.toLowerCase() === 'checkbox') {
                        sum -= parseFloat(thisInput.value);
                    }
                }
                totalcost.value = (sum > 0) ? sum.toFixed(2) : "";
            }
    }
    return null;
}());
</script>
```

Comment: `totalcost.value = (sum > 0) ? sum.toFixed(2) : "0.00";` needs to be used with @martynas's solution.

Comment: ok , when i checked ckeck box and unchecked 0.00 will disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify default `value` for the input:

```
<input type="text" id="totalcost" value="0.00">
```

Set the default value to `0.00`:

```
totalcost.value = (sum > 0) ? sum.toFixed(2) : "0.00";
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jr5CY/)**

```
var clickHandlers = (function () {
    var form1 = document.getElementById("form1"),
        totalcost = document.getElementById("totalcost"),
// if this is always the last input in the form, we could avoid hitting document again with
// totalcost  = form1[form1.length - 1];
        sum = 0;
    form1.onclick = function (e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var thisInput = e.target || e.srcElement;
        if (thisInput.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {
            if (thisInput.checked) {
                sum  += parseFloat(thisInput.value);
            }  else {
                if (thisInput.type.toLowerCase() === 'checkbox') {
                    sum -= parseFloat(thisInput.value);
                }
            }
            totalcost.value = (sum > 0) ? sum.toFixed(2) : "0.00";
        }
    }
    return null;
}());
```

Comment: ok, thank it's work 

and i have some question , how can i show 0.00 or sum number on 2 place ?

Comment: Could you please clarify: "on 2 place"?

Comment: now number will display in 
`<input type="text" id="totalcost" value="0.00">`

but i want to display sum number in

`<input type="text" id="totalcost" value="0.00">`

and

`<input type="text" id="totalcost2" value="0.00">`

how can i do that ?

Comment: If i understand you correctly - you want to have 2 inputs showing exact same value? http://jsfiddle.net/jr5CY/1/

Comment: and my last question? how can i set width of 
`<input type="text" id="totalcost" value="0.00">`

with data ?

Comment: width of input with data? What do you mean? Just use CSS to adjust the width of the input: http://jsfiddle.net/sza3K/

Comment: no no , i mean if sum value is `9` i want to set width `<input type="text" id="totalcost">` = 50 px but if sum value is `100000` i want to set width `<input type="text" id="totalcost">` = 200 px

Comment: Set up an onChange listener and adjust the width accordingly: http://jsfiddle.net/arRP8/

Comment: Hit `Enter` key after you change something